# Ext.Ajax.request works fine in ie but fails in firefox

Tags: ajax, firefox, extjs

I am trying to get the contents from a file using **Ext.Ajax.request**, using get method, and giving a URL and of data type json. I am able to get the contents of the file in ie without any issues, but Ext.Ajax.request is not working fine in Firefox, even the failure message is not being returned. 
We are using ExtJS version 4.1.3.
I have googled on this and found that this problem is faced by many people but I am not able to find a solution out there.
Can anyone please help on this.

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Vasavi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here works fine in FF on my side:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['text', 'value'],
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'resources/data/countries.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

This uses Ext.Ajax or Ext.data.Connection (basically the same) under the hood. Note that the path is relative, so it pulls a file from the server, not from the local filesystem. FF often failed silently when violating access rights (sandboxing) in my testing.